# Can't build tdbc 1.0.6 on mint

Tags: ubuntu, tcl, linux-mint, tdbc

I am finally updating the OS on my ancient laptop after using ubuntu 12.04 for 5+ years.

As far as I can make out, Ubuntu no longer support 32-bit systems, so I have installed mint. I have a shedload of Tcl scripts and have always relied on ActiveTcl in the past, but they seem no longer to provide a batteries-included distribution, so I've downloaded and built tcl8.7a1 and tk8.7a1 which I have installed in /opt/tcl8.7a1.

One script that I want to continue to use fails with `can't find package tdbc::mysql`, so I am trying to build the tdbc package (to be followed by tdbc::mysql and tdbc::sqlite3). I have started by cloning the fossil repository at core.tcl.tk/tdbc.

However,

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/tcl8.7a1 --with-tcl=/opt/tcl8.7a1/lib
```

fails with

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in tclconfig "."/tclconfig
```

I had a look through `configure` and couldn't see that the symbols set up around where the error occurs were being used anywhere else, so I just commented out the error line and a few more.

This allowed the `configure` command to complete, and I was able to `make` without errors, however, `make install` failed because it couldn't find install.sh - maybe those variables are used somewhere :-).

What should I do to get around the `configure` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off using the production release:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/8.6.8/
The db access packages are included and will be built for you.